# Javascript regular expression to match id in string

Tags: javascript

Javascript:

```
var data='<div id="hai">this is div</div>';
```

Now how to write regular expression to retrive only id "hai". The expected output is,

```
var id = regularexpression(data);
```

Now id should contains "hai". Can any one help me to write regular expression in javascript ?

Comment: Why regex? Why not parse that as HTML or some other string manipulation method? What can that div contain? Only text or more HTML?

Comment: Using simple jquery you can also find id attribute value of particular div.
$('div').attr('id');  You can learn about regular expression from below websites: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html

Comment: @AshishPatel: 1: don't use `attr` to get the `id` property. 2: don't use w3schools as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex pattern `/(id="(.*?)(\"))/g`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tMBUvJ/1)**

```js
var data='<div id="hai"  class="hello">this is div</div>';
console.log(/(id="(.*?)(\"))/g.exec(data)[2])
```

***Alternate***

```js
var data='<div id="hai" >this is div</div>';
document.body.innerHTML +=data;
var id=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id;
console.log(id)
```

Comment: Your `regex` gives wrong output. Consider this test case `<div id="hai" class="hello">this is div</div>`

Comment: Did you check with this `<div id="hai" class="hello">this is div</div>` string? It's giving me `hai" class="Hello` as output.

Comment: without even checking the solution, the OP accepted your answer. Great!

Answer (score -1):

This below regex (**id=\"(.*?)\"**) will give you the same result as you expected.

```js
 
var data='<div id="hai">this is div</div>';
console.log(/id=\"(.*?)\"/g.exec(data)[1])
```